# Jsoup Html parsing query

Tags: java, android-studio, jsoup

im a newb with Jsoup, i would like parse this code:

```
<span class="vi-tm-left">
                <span>(27 apr 2018</span>
                <span class="endedDate">19:17:55 CEST)</span>
</span>
```

in order to get :

27 apr 2018 19:17:55 CEST

any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have selected the document in the `doc` variable, and that the `vi-tm-left` class is unique:

```
final String dateWithBrackets = doc.select("span.vi-tm-left").first().text();
final String date = dateWithBrackets.substring(1, dateWithBrackets.length() - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

An example to get it:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsoupMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<span class=\"vi-tm-left\"><span>(27 apr 2018</span><span class=\"endedDate\">19:17:55 CEST)</span></span>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        String text = doc.select("span.vi-tm-left").text().replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
        System.out.println(text);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
        String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
                + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element firstSpan = doc.select("span.vi-tm-left").first().text();
        Element secondSpan = doc.select("span.vi-tm-left").get(1).text();

        String result = firstSpan.text() + secondSpan.text();
        result = result.substring(1, dateWithBrackets.length() - 2);
```